# (Learning) Is it good practice to build your user-side site off your own API, or have your API be separate from core functionality?

Tags: django, api

I'm currently learning python/django, and I'm building a small program to look up legislators and their stances on political isses like net neutrality, patent reform, etc.

In the near-long term, I'd like to release an API for people to use to easily access the data I am collecting. The main lookup site will be a GUI that lays out this information (with some added fanciness, like grades and a history chart).

Is it good practice to use your own API? Or is it not a practice at all (i.e., it would be good if I did it, but it's not really necessary)?

Answer (score 3):

It's always a good idea. It's called "dogfooding" (as in, "eating your own dogfood").

The main danger is that you take the view that your api works for your use-cases, and that is sufficient. The flip-side is of course the inner-platform effect.